# Using NPM for dependency instead of link/script tags

Tags: reactjs, npm, codemirror

So I'm using this library

[Component Playground](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/component-playground)

Which is a react component that lets the user do live editing of react components and leverages code mirror.

It makes me setup code mirror by including that library with tags -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.0.0/codemirror.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.0.0/theme/monokai.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.0.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.0.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>
```

However, I'd like to use npm for this, maybe

`https://github.com/JedWatson/react-codemirror`

but when I do, I get that `CodeMirror is not defined`

Is there a way for me to use npm to get the code mirror dependency?

Comment: `npm install codemirror` ?

Comment: @FelixKling already tried that - didn't work.

Comment: @praks5432 How did `npm install codemirror` not work? The `codemirror` package is available on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/codemirror. What specifically was the error?

Comment: I installed it..and got `CodeMirror is not defined`@Liongold

Comment: Even after looking into the `component-playground` code and putting in a `require('codemirror')`, I lose the errors, but I get no code mirror component..unless I add the stylesheets